# How to edit List Item Elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change "Milk" to oat milk by using some javascript that will be run through the google dev console.
The HTML looks like;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="groceries-section">
      <h1>Our Shopping List</h1>
      <ul id="grocery-list">
        <li>Milk</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm able to get the id using;

```
document.getElementById("grocery-list")
```

but I am unsure how to access the "Milk" li.
I'm new to this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate question, so I'll just post a comment here: `const li = document.querySelector('#grocery-list > li')`

Comment: I'd use CSS selectors instead: `document.querySelector("#grocery-list li")`.

Comment: I'd rather assign a class or identifier to the Milk <li> element. It's very uncertain that this will be the only <li> element @trynalearn1010 will add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `querySelector` to get the first `li` element inside the `ul` element with the `id` `grocery-list`.

```js
document.getElementById("grocery-list").querySelector("li").innerHTML = "Oat Milk";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only change the first `li` element from `ul`:

```
document.querySelector('ul li').innerText = 'Aloha'
```

If you have multiple `<li>Whatever</li>` you could do the following:

```
document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach(el=>{
    el.innerText = 'Milka'
})
```

If you want to select only the `li` with Milk value, from multiple elements, you could do:

```
document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach(el=>{
    if(el.innerText == 'Milk'){
        el.innerText = 'Oat Milk'
    }
})
```